# Generate SIMPLE Paypal buttons dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I wanted to add PayPal functionality to my Wordpress plug-in, so I ventured over to PayPal's developer page and scanned through it.  I couldn't help but notice how vague and complicated their documentation was.

On their [button manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/button-manager/) page, step 4 literally says " ... develop the API code necessary to create and manage your buttons."  This is not helpful whatsoever.  With a little more digging, I found this [PHP SDK](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#button-manager), but implementing it is poorly explained and I can't follow it.  To be honest, it looks like overkill anyway. All I want to do is send basic information:

- Merchant's e-mail (to which payment will be sent)
- Item cost
- Item quantity

Logging into my own PayPal account and generating a button using their form **will not work** for this. I am trying to generate a button dynamically, based on the information the user enters into the plug-in.  I would also prefer the method to be more secure than using the HTML hidden input fields.

If there is absolutely no easy way to send PayPal these three simple things, then I would greatly appreciate seeing a more thorough explanation of the SDK.  I do not know what composer is, nor what bootstrap.php is supposed to be, nor do I know where to save the files that use the SDK's functionality.  Once those questions are answered, I only want to know how to send those three things and the bare necessities.  I don't need all this extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do it is to generate direct URL, something like: (you can click it)
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=yourpaypalbusiness@hotmail.com&notify_url=http://example.com/ipn.php&item_name=myitem&item_number=1&currency_code=USD&rm=2&amount=49.99&quantity=1

This way you can populate URL query parameters from your database/plugin.

I hope so it helped.

Comment: when I change " ... business=yourpaypalbusiness@hotmail.com ... " to my own merchant e-mail address, I am redirected to a blank white page and nothing happens...

Comment: Have you created business email address inside your PayPal sandbox account?

Comment: I am testing the live version, not the sandbox.  And yes, I have a PayPal business account with the e-mail address I am using.

Comment: Can you paste link you are using here, exclude your email address because of privacy.

Comment: `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=[excluded]&notify_url=http://example.com/ipn.php&item_name=myitem&item_number=1&currency_code=USD&rm=2&amount=49.99&quantity=1`

Comment: I have tested it using fake email address:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=asdaddasadsdasdasds@live.com&notify_url=http://example.com/ipn.php&item_name=myitem&item_number=1&currency_code=USD&rm=2&amount=49.99&quantity=1

If you own PayPal business account, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122020/discussion-between-asmir-zahirovic-and-jon-dewitt).

Comment: UPDATE:  I try in a private browsing window without using cookies or cache, and it works.  So my problem is related to that somehow.